# How to check my field `username` on unique in table `User` except current user's username in Yii2

Tags: validation, yii2

In view my field `username` always filled by current user's username. And it always (on submit) sends username value to my `InformationForm` and validate it on unique like next:

```
[['username'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => 'username', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username can not be taken.'],
```

And it say's that this username has already been taken. So i want to check my value `username` just then, whet it's not my username. It's like
My current username in database -> Bob
My value in view in field `username` -> Bob
I click `Submit` and it should't check if this username is unique (obviously because it's my username)

And just then, when my current username in database -> Bob
And value in view in field `username` -> John
And i click `Submit` - is should check if this username is unique

I know about "custom validator" so i can validate my field using my own written method in my `InformationForm`. And i want to find how to do all i wrote here except using my own written method in my `InformationForm`.

Comment: Did you create a model InformationForm just for getting this inputs? Because you don't have to. And that is probably why you are facing this problem with unique validator.

Comment: @Clyff, i create model InformationForm for validation my fields and putting them (if they are new) to database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `when` property for `unique` validator.

And your rules in models is:

```
[
    ['username'], 'unique', 
    'targetAttribute' => 'username', 
    'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 
    'message' => 'This username can not be taken.',
    'when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->username != Yii::$app->user->identity->getUsername(); // or other function for get current username
    }
],
```

You can refer to yii2 document: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$when-detail

Goodluck and have fun!

Comment: I have next
`[['username'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => 'username', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'when' =>
    function ($model, $attribute)
    {
     $isNew = false;
     if($model->$attribute != User::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->one()->$attribute) {
      $isNew = true;
     }
     return $isNew;
    },
    'message' => 'This username can not be taken.'],`
And i have error like this
`call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'uniqueExceptItSelf' not found or invalid function name`

Comment: I use your code, and it worked!
My Yii2 version is 2.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Rule:

```
['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => self::class, 'when' => [$this, 'whenSelfUnique']
```

When handler method:

```
public function whenSelfUnique($model, $attribute) {
    /**
     * @var ActiveRecord $model
     */
    $condition = $model->getOldPrimaryKey(true);
    return !self::find()->where(array_merge($condition, [$attribute => $model->$attribute]))->exists();
}
```

or

```
public function whenSelfUnique($model, $attribute) {
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return \Yii::$app->user->identity->$attribute !== $model->$attribute;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Play with scenarios