# How to remove code repetition in Yii2 validators method `when`?

Tags: validation, yii2, repeat

You have to read my previous problem to understand what i'm talking here about([Link to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253470/how-to-check-my-field-username-on-unique-in-table-user-except-current-users/38257063#38257063)). So it was solved.

But i have a lot of fields in my view that are always filled by current user's value. And it's code repetition when i doing next

```
[['new_email'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => 'email', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User',
            'when' => function ($model, $attribute) {
                $this->isNewEmail = false;
                if($model->$attribute != User::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->one()->email) {
                    $this->isNewEmail = true;
                }
                return $this->isNewEmail;
            },
            'message' => 'This email can not be taken.'],
```

And this

```
[['first_name'], 'string', 'min' => 4, 'max' => 50,
            'when' => function ($model, $attribute) {
                $this->isNewFirstName = false;
                if($model->$attribute != User::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->one()->first_name) {
                    $this->isNewFirstName = true;
                }
                return $this->isNewFirstName;
            },
        ],
```

And so on.

What can i do to remove this code repetition. Or is there are somewhere exists module or component for Yii2 just like for this situation like mine? Or is there are somewhere exists core validator for my issue? Or i doomed forever to do all of this code repetition?)

Comment: why don't you do this before model->validate()? also provide more of you action php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that 2 `when` callable function have same structure. So you can write a simple function like that:

```
/**
 * @param $model ActiveRecord
 * @param $attribute string
 * @return bool
 */
public function checkUniqueAttribute($model, $attribute)
{
    return $model->$attribute != $model::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->one()->$attribute;
}
```

And use it in your rules:

```
[
    ['new_email'], 'unique',
    'targetAttribute' => 'email',
    'targetClass' => '\common\models\User',
    'message' => 'This email can not be taken.',
    'when' => 'checkUniqueAttribute',
],
[
    ['first_name'], 'unique',
    'targetAttribute' => 'first_name',
    'targetClass' => '\common\models\User',
    'message' => 'This first name can not be taken.',
    'when' => 'checkUniqueAttribute',
],
[['first_name'], 'string', 'min' => 4, 'max' => 50,],
```

Hope it useful.

Goodluck and have fun!

Comment: Yes, that's good. But there are not always my field's names in model is equal to field's names in database in table (but i think that it will be batter to have equal names of my properties in my model and equal names of my fields in database's table)

Comment: And i want to avoid to touch my database when my field is exactly the same as i database.